# IS_REQUIRED error on Migration from Magento 1.9.2.2 to 2.2.6

Tags: magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, data-migration-tool

I'm trying some dry run to migrate data from Magento 1.9.2.2 to 2.2.6.
After some adjustment, I'm stuck on the following error

```
[2018-10-28 14:57:56][INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: Map Step]: started
26% [=======>--------------------] Remaining Time: 2 mins
[2018-10-28 14:58:59][ERROR]: Record structure does not contain field is_required

  [Migration\Exception]
  Data Migration failed
```

In map-eav xml there is a rule to transform it

```
    <transform>
        <field>eav_attribute.is_required</field>
        <handler class="\Migration\Handler\GetDestinationValue" />
    </transform>
```

but I don't know where to check and how to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with [this fix](https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/commit/13728b3d6872ac3f12f07efccf04f28060b9fbec)

There are some files to upgrade.